# Can I start a question with a base verb?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Can I start a question with a verb without a subject? About the following sentence, which one is correct?

> Want to buy these products? Please contact us now.

> Wanting to buy these products? Please contact us now.

Comment: I'm curious about it, too, because I usually see this form in work correspondence, and started using it by myself

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You see this kind of construction in the short "punchy" phrases that advertisement writers use. They aren't suitable for use in an essay or business letter, for example.

Now, in English, it is possible to make even a single noun into a question by intonation:

> Some cats followed me home yesterday.
>
> Cats?

The rising intonation forms the question.  A similar thing can be done with the infinitive verb in a "do you" question

> Take two bottles into the shower? Not me! I wash and go!

Or the participle in an "are you" question:

> Feeling a bit under the weather?  Go have a lie-down.

Such constructions are natural enough in conversation, and are freely used by advertisers.

Your second example sentence is not correct, because you don't use the present continuous with "want" (in this sense)  You don't say "I am wanting to buy these products."  But "Hoping to buy these products? Contact us now." would be okay, in this context.

Comment: A number of UK regional dialects allow "I am wanting to buy these products", but it is, as you say not standard.

Comment: What regional dialects use that?

Comment: It's possible in Scots dialects. It's speculated that it may be a garlic influence.

Comment: Thats my most favorite typo ever :D

Comment: "Gaelic" influence !

Answer (score 6):

Neither of them is formally grammatical, but implying "[Do you] want to" is fine in informal English, and common on shopping sites. "Wanting" sounds stilted in this context, and has the unfortunate secondary meaning of "absent; lacking".